# How to extract datas when I hover over an icon in windows system or in program?

Tags: python, hover, extract

I try to make some automation in Python and I don't find this mode anywhere.
I have found lots of hover extraction with webdrivers but I don't use any browser. I just want to retrieve datas from the label what I see when I hover mouse over icons in a program.

Or could I use selenium in this case too? Pls help me how!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Congratulations on your first post. What have you tried? Add your code and any errors/output to your question and that will help others find solutions to your problem. It may be helpful to you to read: [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Thank you! I didn't get any error, because I didn't write anything about this project because the first thing what I have to know: Is it possible to extract the tooltip text when I hover mouse over an icon in an application in windows? I want to automatize a process and for this I need the text in appearing label.